# How to loop through a dynamic taxonomy vocabulary and if term is chosen, do an action?

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms, rules

My problem is as follows:

- I have a taxonomy vocabulary with terms, which are changing from time to time.
- I have two node types --> **type 1** and **type 2**
- **Type 1**  has a taxonomy term reference field
- **Type 2** has an entity reference field which can be prepopulated with the module "entity reference prepopulate"

If I create a new node of node type *type 1* then a rule should check which terms are selected and create a new node of *type 2* for each selected term automatically.

The entity reference field of the new *type 2* node should be prepopulated with a reference back to the original *type 1* node.

Because the terms of the vocabulary are changing, the check up by the rule should be IMHO dynamic.

*Dummy-Code:*

**If** a new node of node *type 1* is saved,**then** check which taxonomy terms are selected.

**for each** selected term:

- create a new node of *type 2*
- and prepopulate the entity reference field of node *type 2* with the value of node *type 1*.

I tried it with the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, but there seems no for..each control loop available.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **If** a new node of node *type 1* is saved,

= Rules Event: After saving content, of type "type 1".

> **then** check which taxonomy terms are selected.

= Rules Action: Create a Rules loop, which iterates over each of the selected taxonomy terms, assume you use a name for each list item like "`selected_term`".

> **for each** selected term:

= Rules Action (which is part of the loop), in which you perform a "Rules Component", and which uses as parameter the "`selected_term`".

> - create a new node of *type 2*

= 1st Rules Action performed as part of the Rules Component, which is to "Create an entity" (a node of "type 2").

> - and prepopulate the entity reference field of node *type 2* with the value of node *type 1*.

= 2nd Rules Action performed as part of the Rules Component, which is to "set a data value", for the entity reference field, as part of the entity (node) that got created in the previous Rules Action, and followed by a Rules Action to "save the entity".

Refer to the [List and loops](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/lists-and-loops) video for more details about processing lists and loops via Rules.

**Note**: no need for the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module ...

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand that a loop in this case is similar to for..each in other programming languages. The video link helped me very much :)

Comment: merci (oeps: thank you) for the accept, and +1! Rules is great, but there are a few things (such as lists and loops) that aren't obvious to get used to. Actually I also first learned about it via that very same video link I added. Next question? Possibly also about Rules ...